# Shift+Alt доставляет неудобства при печатании

Tags: windows, клавиатура

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с раздражающей проблемой при печатании в таких программах как Skype, MS Word и некоторых других.

Когда я меняю язык через Shift+Alt иногда проскакивает обычное нажатие Alt, которое Windows по-умолчанию считает вызовом верхнего навигационного меню активного окна (не во всех программах оно есть). Там где есть такое меню, при переключении языка Alt ведет себя совершенно непредсказуемо, и может либо пропустить, либо взять и выделить верхнее меню.

Во втором случае, если срабатывает это выделение, печатание прерывается и вызывается случайный пункт меню одной из буквенных кнопок. Особенно в Word, в нем очень много пунктов меню назначены на буквенные кнопки.

Возможно ли как-то решить эту проблему? По-моему раньше (в Windows 7, сейчас стоит Windows 10) Alt вел себя более адекватно и не вызывал верхнее меню при переключении языка. Теперь же он срабатывает иногда при комбинации Alt+Shift.
Нельзя ли вообще отключить Alt как вызов меню?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Ну есть варианты, например:

1. Проверить с другой клавиатурой, что это у вас не проблема с клавишей Shift (она может плохо прожиматься от изношенности).
2. Научиться нажимать Shift чуть раньше, а отпускать чуть позже чем Alt.
3. Изменить комбинацию переключения языков на Ctrl-Shift (потребуется привыкать).

Comment: По второму пункту всё наоборот. Если зажать **Alt** раньше чем **Shift** и отпустить после смены языка, то вызов верхнего навигационного меню не сработает. Тоже на днях столкнулся с этой проблемой, т.к. привык начинать с **Shift**.

Answer (score 0):

Для переключения языка в Office использовать Windows + Space

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Была такая же проблема
Но со временем я начал делать так:
Зажимаю Shift и только после этого нажимаю alt, так же это можно применять если сворачиваете вкладки, зажать alt и после нажимать tab, выбирая нужную вкладку

Comment: суть вашего ответа изложена в другом ответе более пяти лет назад.